# Calling method with complex arguments

Tags: python

Whats the best practice for calling a function with a complex set of arguments?

I've seen a **1** and **2** in most codebases, but I haven't seen **3**. 
Since it's almost impossible to search for `**{` in codebases, does anyone know why this pattern isn't used more often?

I'm using Google's [Sheet's API v4](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/dyn/sheets_v4.spreadsheets.html#batchUpdate) as a demonstration, which has a complex API.

---

### 1. Calling with arguments (Most commonly observed)

- Requires building the inner structure first

```py
body = {
    "body": {
        "requests": [
            {
                "addSheet": {
                    "properties": {
                        "title": "some title"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
request = service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(
    spreadsheetId=spreadsheetId, body=body)
```

### 2. Define a `dict` first (Similar vertical parsing to 1)

- Cleaner to see on invocation
- May allow for manipulation of values

```py
params = {
    "spreadsheetId": spreadsheetId
    "body": {
        "requests": [
            {
                "addSheet": {
                    "properties": {
                        "title": "some title"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
request = service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(**params)
```

### 3. Inline a `dict` (Not seen in practice, why?)

- Clear intent (single-source, fixed properties)
- Single pass vertical parsing

```py
request = service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(**{
    "spreadsheetId": spreadsheetId
    "body": {
        "requests": [
            {
                "addSheet": {
                    "properties": {
                        "title": "some title"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
})
```

Comment: Code Review requires concrete code from a project, with sufficient context for reviewers to understand how that code is used. Pseudocode, stub code, **hypothetical code**, obfuscated code, and generic best practices are outside the scope of this site. Please take a look at the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 2):

As general practice, I prefer using positional arguments simply because they're easier to typecheck with `mypy`.  In the case of using some external API that doesn't have python3 type annotations (booo) I'd create a stub file that includes all of the types that I'm using and then code against that.

For your example, a quick search didn't turn up any existing mypy stubs, so I assume I'm stuck writing my own.  Here's how I'm gonna do it for the code sample you've provided:

```
from typing import List, TypedDict

class _Properties(TypedDict, total=False):
    title: str

class _AddSheet(TypedDict, total=False):
    properties: _Properties

class _Request(TypedDict, total=False):
    addSheet: _AddSheet

class _Body(TypedDict, total=False):
    requests: List[_Request]

def batchUpdate(spreadsheetId: str, body: _Body) -> None: ...
```

This is a very incomplete type declaration for that potentially massive `_Body` object (also, note that I'm assuming that none of these fields are required; omit the `total=False` if you want to enforce totality), but since I'm probably not going to use all of those fields, my strategy is going to be to add them to my declaration as I use them, and have that be the source of truth (i.e. as long as I declare it correctly once in that file, mypy will make sure I use it correctly everywhere else).

Now I can call that function in my code like this:

```
batchUpdate(
    spreadsheetId, { 
        'requests': [{ 
            'addSheet': { 
                'properties': { 
                    'title': "some title" 
                } 
            } 
        }]
    }
)
```

(BTW, if you want to completely ignore my advice about typing, this is the calling syntax I'd use regardless.)

The benefit of having added typing is that if I typo something, e.g. I misspell "properties", I'll get an error from mypy like this:

```
spreadsheet.py:22: error: Extra key 'prperties' for TypedDict "_AddSheet"
```

If I forget that `requests` is a list and I omit the brackets, I get:

```
spreadsheet.py:21: error: Incompatible types (expression has type "Dict[str, Dict[str, Dict[str, str]]]", TypedDict item "requests" has type "List[_Request]")
```

Getting a static error like this is a lot easier than having a typo in my server API call that results in a (possibly cryptic) runtime error.

My experience is that using the `**kwargs` syntax generally makes it harder to enforce good typing, so I tend to avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I'm not the super duper python crack.

When discussing such questions I usually like to figure out first, what's the thing we're optimizing for.
If it's performance you might make other decisions than when its maintainability or readability.

For readability all of them are fine and have small benefits or disadvantages.
In the end the style wins you're most used to. However, there might be technical dis/advantages which I'm not aware of.

Option 1 has in favor that the call is a bit more explicit about what its doing, because there is one important argument explicitly added (spreadsheetId) and a number of arguments with less importance.

If you scroll over the code, 1 has a small advantage there I'd say.

I don't exactly get, what you mean by

> Since it's almost impossible to search for **{ in codebases,

But my gut says, if you need to search something as a string other than a name, there is something odd, which needs to be fixed.

Maybe your parameters have a degree of complexity where it would make sense to add functions which create them (and also document their intention through their name).

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. Please note that it's considered bad style to answer off-topic questions. We have plenty of unanswered, on-topic questions that could use your attention instead. Thank you.